# Code-colored text in Inkscape or Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, fonts, vector, plugin

I would like to create a vector of text, code to be exact. I do have quite a bit of code to use and don't want to color it all (brackets and all) by hand.

Do you know a way of doing it? A plugin maybe?

I tried print screen -> tracing, but that effects in bad quality.

Comment: Are you looking for something that will auto-color type? It's unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste to text editor as rich text  -> export to pdf -> import as vector

Answer (score 0):

check this one, there is a script.
i haven't tried it. looks like colored code  https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/making-a-code-syntax-highlighter-for-illustrator/m-p/10239005